# How to block guest access to admin routes that arent setup or are prefixed

Tags: php, laravel

Here is the routes file.

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'namespace' => 'Admin'],
function()
{
    Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController');

    //customers
    Route::get('customers', 'CustomerController@index');
    Route::get('customers/view/{id}', 'CustomerController@show');

    //listing
    Route::get('listing/restaurants', 'ListingController@restaurants');
    Route::get('listing/dishes', 'ListingController@dishes');

    //email
    Route::get('emails', 'EmailController@index');

    //settings
    Route::resource('settings', 'SettingController');

    //json
    Route::get('json/dish_schedule', 'JsonController@dish_schedule');

});
```

when I visit /auth or /admin without any other segments i am able to see the admin page. How do i block these and redirect the user back to the login page?

Answer (score 0):

You have the middleware `auth` specified, take a look at `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php` to change the redirect location of the middleware when users are not authenticated.

If that middleware is unavailable for some reason, you'll need to look at creating a middleware and adding it into your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file.

If you're asking about *authorization* (only allowing specific users to access these routes), you'll need to take a look at policies: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#creating-policies